# JavaFX, student registration style system without database

Tags: java, javafx, model, tableview, selection

I've been creating a small sample project to display my learnings in JavaFX, and it's completed as far as functionality. My problem now is that The lead instructor has asked me to show a database style relation between the student page and the faculty page, showing that a student has tried to add a course. I've got one page for the student where they can select a course from a table. I then have a faculty page that displays a current schedule table, and a tab on the pane that allows the faculty to add or delete a class. I'm wondering the best way without a database to show the s student has selected a course from the table which they choose to register for. I'm Using TableView for all tables, creating observable lists where I can add items and everything displays perfectly on the tables. I have the add and delete functions working perfectly well also. I only need to find a way to transfer the selection from the student to be viewable by the faculty, perhaps in a text file or something like that. Any suggestion or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed several ways. One you have suggested yourself.

You could write the data to a text file using the PrintWriter class (java.io.PrintWriter). You can recall the data by using the Scanner class.

If there is no need for the data to be stored after closing your program, the textile will be redundant. It would be better practice to store the data in an object/instance which can be aggregated by the faculty.

For a more specific answer, be more specific in your question.